# NodeJS w/Express eliminate Error: Cannot GET /xyz

Tags: node.js, express, routes

my problem is, if an user type to the adress bar www.example.com/xyz, the user got the error Cannot get /xyz. My question is how I can catch all the url params after "/".

I thought that the solution could have something like this.

```
app.get('CATCH ALL URLS except /', function (req, res){
     res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Do you actually want to capture the contents after the / or do you really just want to set up a default `GET` handler that sends `index.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I set up my routing for express.

```
app.get('/', routes.site.index);

app.get('/terms', routes.terms.list);

app.post('/terms', routes.terms.create);

app.get('/terms/:id', routes.terms.show);
app.post('/terms/:id', routes.terms.edit);
app.del('/terms/:id', routes.terms.del);

/*Handling wrong urls*/
app.get("/*", routes.site.wrong);
```

`:id` will be available as `req.params.id` in your method.

Answer (score 2):

Just define two routes, the first for / and the second for the rest:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // Do something for /
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```